# C#/SQL: Execute Multiple Insert/Update in ONE Transaction

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, insert

I have a customer entity with 10 Properties.

- 7 of those properties are saved in the customer table.
- 3 of those properties are saved in the test table.

The 3 properties in test table are CustomerId, Label, Text.

When I query these 3 properties I get 3 dataset like this:

```
CustomerId | Label  | Text
1005       | blubb  | What a day
1006       | hello  | Sun is shining
0007       |        |
```

When I save them I have to call my stored procedure 3 times on the test table

In my SP I check wether the dataset with the specific customerId AND Label already exists
then I do an UPDATE else an INSERT.

How would you call the stored procedure 3 times with all CommandText, CommandType, ExecuteNonQuery etc stuff ?

Comment: Is there an object that represents the customer, or the entities that you are wanting to insert into the test table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way : use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class.

Simply put the call into a block like :

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()){

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring)
    {
        conn.Open();
... do the call to sproc

        ts.Complete();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

[Edit] I also added the SqlConnection, because I'm very fan of this pattern. The using keyword ensure the connection is closed and the transcation rollback if something wrong happened

Comment: Since you have the using() {} feature why do you also call the conn.Close() method inside it?It is redundant

Comment: @Redg: it's a matter of readability (and thus, a personal preference). It's true that the `Dispose()` method of the SqlConnection will close it if needed. But it won't close it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a SqlTransaction spanning three ExecuteNonQuery is the simplest, but some alternatives:

- use the XML datatype to pass all three in as XML; parse the XML (SQL server has functions for this) in the sproc into 3 records
- use a "table valued parameter" to pass them in a single call - note this needs additional definition at the DB to represent the structured data
- if the data volume is huge (3000 rather than 3), SqlBulkCopy into a staging table, then run a sproc to move the data into the real table in one set-based operation

Finally, watch out for the "inner platform effect" - it sounds a bit like a DB inside a DB.

Comment: do you have me a little snippet for the sqltransaction spanning 3 ExecuteNonQuery, please?

Comment: @Lisa I'm sure MSDN has... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several classes that inherit from [DbTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbtransaction.aspx).  The documentation for [SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx) has sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate your INSERTs into a transaction. The bad way to do it is to use a TransactionScope in ADO.NET, the good way is to write a stored procedure and BEGIN and COMMIT/ROLLBACK your transaction inside you proc. You don't want to go back and forth form client to server while maintaing a transaction, because you will hurt concurreny and performance (exclusive locks are hold on the resources inserted until the transaction ends).

BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT
    INSERT
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() -- you can use THROW in SQL Server 2012 to retrhrow the error
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH